# CentOS: Avoid that ALT-F4 switches to console

Tags: centos, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

At least every Linux system that I worked with used the convention to switch to the non-graphical consoles by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and so on.

Recently, I installed CentOS 6.3 on a machine. The installation is non-customized and uses Gnome 2.

To my surprise <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> switches to console. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> then brings you back to the XServer. How can I change the keybinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

It also seems to bypass Gnome's key bindings. In Gnome, I tried to define <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> as close window, but it does not work but still switches to the console.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a bad `Ctrl` key on your keyboard?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The keyboard itself is fine, but as it seems there was a temporary software problem. After restarting the machine, the problem is gone.

Comment: I have this problem Too...
I use Manjaro... Had you solve your problem?

Comment: @Jao I did not find the reason why it sometimes happened, nor was I able to reliably reproduce it. As I didn't use that CentOS installation myself on a daily basis, I have only seen that strange behaviour when I initially set up the system.

Comment: Parallels Desktop on Mac, with CentOS 6.8 Virtual Machine, same problem, `ALT` + `F4` switches to console, `ALT` + `F1` back to the XServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem vanished after a restart. I can only speculate about the reasons. It is possible to set <kbd>CTRL</kbd> per software. Maybe that happened. I didn't mess around with `keymap` or anything like that, so I don't know what caused the problem.

Sorry, for the false alarm. :-(

**Edit:**

From time to time, the problem repeats. It vanishes with a restart. I still don't know why.

**Update:**

Had the problem again on two Arch Linux systems. It occurred exactly after a Linux kernel update, but before the system was rebooted. After the reboot, the problem was gone on both systems.

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity, also fixed by rebooting. Interestingly, after logging back in, the window I was trying to close actually closes. Also, `Alt`+Left and `Alt`+Right (arrow keys) also flip through TTYs when the problem is occurring. This is annoying because that's supposed to go forward an backward in a web browser.

Comment: Same problem here.